# updated libraries are incompatible

Tags: eclipse, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, ubuntu-11.10, ftdi

**OS ->** ubuntu 11.10( Yes,its quite old version but unfortunately we cant upgrade it)

**Updated driver** -> ftdi driver from libftd2xx.so.1.1.1 to libftd2xx.so.1.1.12

**IDE** -> ecillpse

**Issue ->**  failed to include update library

**Error ->**

1. /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so when
   searching for -lftd2xx
2. /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
       /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a when searching for -lftd2xx

**Overview:**
I have embedded system which uses ftdi chip. I have to include some new functions in my coding so for that reason I have upgraded the library . Below are the following steps I have followed

- tar xfvz libftd2xx1.1.12.tar.gz
- cd build/arm926
- cp lib* /usr/local/lib

*Copies the libraries to a central location.*

- chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.1.1.12
- ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.1.1.12 /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so

*Building the shared-object examples.*

- cd examples
- make -B ( I followed these steps as written in their documentation but no idea why I did)

*Run ldconfig*

- sudo ldconfig -l /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.1.1.12

Run  file libftd2xx.a

***o/p*** libftd2xx.a: current ar archive

May you guys please help me or point me where I am committing mistake . 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys , I was following instructions from ftdi coument and instead of going into i386  directory , i went into arm986 .